# Damaged volume group on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, lvm, ubuntu-20.04

Ran into a problem with FDISK/LVM: needed to add an additional new disk to Ubuntu Server 20. This has a storage setup using LVM/VG using the default setup configuration.

Used `fdisk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`, to try adding a new partition here (this is the mistake).

Current setup:

```
root@ubuntu-2004:~# lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                       7:0    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2284
loop1                       7:1    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2409
loop2                       7:2    0 61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1518
loop3                       7:3    0 61.9M  1 loop /snap/core20/1434
loop4                       7:4    0 67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835
loop5                       7:5    0 67.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/22753
loop6                       7:6    0   47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16010
loop7                       7:7    0 44.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/15534
sda                         8:0    0   16G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0  512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0 14.5G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 14.5G  0 lvm  /


root@ubuntu-2004:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/loop0: 55.52 MiB, 58204160 bytes, 113680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 55.55 MiB, 58232832 bytes, 113736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 61.95 MiB, 64933888 bytes, 126824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 61.92 MiB, 64909312 bytes, 126776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 67.25 MiB, 70508544 bytes, 137712 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 67.83 MiB, 71106560 bytes, 138880 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 46.98 MiB, 49233920 bytes, 96160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 44.69 MiB, 46845952 bytes, 91496 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 16 GiB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Disk model: Virtual Disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E79D83A9-F2D1-4756-B8B3-1F47B0C95638

Device       Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048  1050623  1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624  3147775  2097152    1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  3147776 33552383 30404608 14.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 14.51 GiB, 15565062144 bytes, 30400512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


root@ubuntu-2004:~# lvs
  LV        VG        Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- <14.50g


root@ubuntu-2004:~# pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/sda3  ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <14.50g    0


root@ubuntu-2004:~# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <14.50g    0


root@ubuntu-2004:~# df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                               915M     0  915M   0% /dev
tmpfs                              192M  964K  191M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   15G  7.8G  5.8G  58% /
tmpfs                              959M     0  959M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              959M     0  959M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2409
/dev/loop0                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop2                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1518
/dev/loop3                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1434
/dev/loop4                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21835
/dev/loop5                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/22753
/dev/loop6                          47M   47M     0 100% /snap/snapd/16010
/dev/loop7                          45M   45M     0 100% /snap/snapd/15534
/dev/sda2                          976M  208M  701M  23% /boot
/dev/sda1                          511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              192M     0  192M   0% /run/user/1000
```

This is the system's LVM containing all partitions. When running fdisk as above, got the notice:

```
Be careful before using the write command.

The old ext4 signature will be removed by a write command.

The device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x622b37e2.
```

The partition table was written, and seemingly overwriting/removing the ext4 signature and setting a dos type disklabel.

The new drive was eventually added to the LVM but when attempting to add free space, by using `resize2fs -p /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv` a message regarding `Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open...`

Seems there is an issue with the VG's integrity, and this will prevent the system from booting. Can I restore the old ext4 signature and then reboot the system safely? Adding the new space is less important and can be done later.

Comment: From the question I don't see where the VG is damaged. You just were trying to partition the LV (which was almost certainly wrong idea), and destroyed the file system which resides on it. // Please don't just refer to the "standard Ubuntu setup", but show the actual configuration (`lvs`, `pvs`, `vgs`, `lsblk`). Also attach the precise command you entered that led to the error message about bad magic.

Comment: It seems the only problem you have is a corrupted ext4. This has been [covered extensively](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=repair+ext4+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: You wiped ext4 superblocks. Now you in the position when you have to recover the data. If the system wasn't rebooted yet, superblock is still in memory and file system might be accessible; I suggest you to copy all files somewhere, recreate everything damaged and copy them back.

Comment: The system is not rebooted and accesible. Backup of files is taken.
By recreate, you mean making a new volume group setup? Can I move the existing disk (which has the root partition) to the new volume group?

Comment: I think your VG is intact. The wiped filesystem on the LV should be repaired somehow. If you have a proper full copy of all files that it contained (with all extended attributes etc.), just reboot into some live system, create a new ext4 file system on the LV (`mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv`) and copy all files back there. That should be enough.

Comment: Thanks. Would be interested to know if a fsck would fix the LVM.

Comment: Your LVM does not need fixing. It is intact. And fsck has nothing to do with LVM.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, @NikitaKipriyanov